# How to globally disable visual-line-mode in Doom Emacs?

Tags: doom, visual-line-mode

In doom emacs, by default (when starting from the default configuration), `visual-line-mode` and `word-wrap` enabled in fundamental, text, prog modes...

I would like to disable the `visual-line-mode` by default and keep word-wrapping. This works when I do `M-x visual-line-mode`, and I have **the desired effect**:

[image]

However I don't know how to do it properly to disable it by default. Few attempts:

1. adding in `config.el`:

   ```
   (global-visual-line-mode 0)
   (visual-line-mode 0)
   ```

   doesn't make any effect
2. Adding the following hook disables word wrapping, and subsequent call to `(toggle-word-wrap)` doesn't work:

   ```
   (add-hook 'text-mode-hook (lambda () (visual-line-mode 0)))
   ```

   so overall the effect is wrong (note: the lines are not unfolded): [image]:

Answer (score 1):

The docs for `global-visual-line-mode` say:

> If called from Lisp, toggle the mode if ARG is ‘toggle’.
> Enable the mode if ARG is nil, omitted, or is a positive number.
> Disable the mode if ARG is a negative number.

So try

```
(global-visual-line-mode -1)
```

Comment: doesn't work. By some reason Doom Emacs keeps setting both variables (`visual-line-mode` and `global-visual-line-mode`) to `t`.

Comment: @RobertZaremba did you manage to do this?

Comment: This is what I'm using:
`(global-visual-line-mode 0)
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook (lambda () (toggle-truncate-lines 0)))`